# Migrate from webpack v1 to v2 with webpack-cli produces error for tsx

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I get this error when running build after migration, and not sure if it can't recognise tsx files or something inside of tsx file that it doesn't like:

> Failed to compile.
>       Error in ./src/index_app.tsx Module parse failed: /src/index_app.tsx Unexpected token (17:26) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>       SyntaxError: Unexpected token (17:26) @ multi main

Content of index_app.tsx:

```
17:const rootReducer = (state:any, action:any) => {
18:    if (action.type === Actions.RESET_GLOBAL_STATE) {
19:        state = undefined;
20:    }
21:    return reducers(state, action)
22:}
```

My webpack config after migration script:

https://pastebin.com/KX02ZRUY

Answer (score 0):

> not sure if it can't recognise tsx files or something inside of tsx file that it doesn't like

Doesn't recognize tsx.

I would change

```
    {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        use: [{
            loader: 'ts-loader'
        }],
    }
```

To standard docs : https://webpack.js.org/guides/webpack-and-typescript/

```
 {
   test: /\.tsx?$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   use: [ 'ts-loader' ]
 }
```